# What is the reason of the structure change of U.S. applied patent during 1963-2011?

Tags: law, application

I am a college student, I want to know why there is a structure change of US applied patent around 1985?

I have been analyzing all the datas of US applied patent from 1963-2011, then I found out there is a structure change around 1985.

Anyone knows what happened to the patent at that time? Or any law influenced? Why there is a dip?

Answer (score 1):

In the early '80 there was a concern that patents were not being enforced with enough uniformity and there was a general feeling that patents were decreasing in value. In response the Federal Courts Improvement Act of 1982 gave one court the responsibility for all patent appeals in order to build expertise and increase uniformity in interpretations in this complex area of law.  Not sure what data you are looking at with a dip, but that was a structural change in the system.